# Executable crashed on Windows 10, can't overwrite it

Tags: windows-10, overwrite

I have *Windows 10* Home and working with *Visual Studio 10 Express, C++*.
So i am doing many compilations per day and some of these executables are going to crash.
However, after a crash i can't overwrite an executable by compilation!
I understand the application might already running but i can't find it!
I have but to restart my PC.

**EDIT:** this never happened with my previous **Windows 7** machine.

I'm compiling via command line using cl.exe and the exact error is the following:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Release/somefile.exe'

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the play button in Visual Studio 10 to compile and run the program in your debug environment? That would catch the exception before it happens, allowing you to jump directly to the line of error.

Comment: @LPChip, i'm not compiling by using the IDE but with command line using cl. I don't have problems with debugging in general, I've already addressed the location of the bug, but i have to restart anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your program still appear in Task Manager's process list? Try killing it from there, or try opening a command prompt and running `taskkill /f /im YOUR_EXECUTABLE.exe`. It will forcibly (`/f`) kill processes matching the filter (`/im`) of your executable's name.

Comment: No, my application is named `winbin.exe` and i can't find any trace of it in Task Manager. However, your command has been worked and my application was found and terminated and was allowed to compile again. However, this seems hacky, wondering why my application doesn't shows up on task manager like any Windows versions did?

Comment: I see you use a debugger to launch your application. It is possible your application is run as a subprocess of the debugger. Try looking for your debugger in Task Manager, and expanding it's subprocesses with the little arrow to the left.

Comment: @user6096479 when you refer to the task manager, Do you actually check the details tab? Only the details tab shows everything.

Comment: what do you mean? i compile my application by command line but i run it normally by double clicking the executable on a windows explorer window. I don't use a debugger of any kind. What kind of debugger application should i search for on Task manager?

Comment: Side note:  i also checked the Details tab as @LPChip mentioned. Still no trace of my application file there. It seems Windows are found my application for termination, but can't find it anywhere to close by single click.